Using Togglz in Springboot application with gradle and admin console does not show up?
I'm trying to implement Togglz in my springboot application, and the admin console continues to display the 404, not found message.
Togglz does seem to be working in a mock API, but I can't get the console to show up. Any help would be appreciated, as I've gone through my configuration and build files and haven't found anything wrong. In addition, nearly all of this code is taken from an online tutorial, so I do feel as if the issue maybe with my configurations?
build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
    implementation("org.togglz:togglz-spring-boot-starter:3.1.2")
    implementation("org.togglz:togglz-console:3.3.3")
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

Features.java
public enum Features implements Feature {

  @EnabledByDefault
  @Label("First Feature")
  MOCK;

  public boolean isActive() {
    return FeatureContext.getFeatureManager().isActive(this);
  }
}

application.yml
togglz:
  features:
    MOCK:
      enabled: true
  features-file: 'com.example.demo.Features'
  console:
    secured: false
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: 'togglz'

togglzconfig
@Component
public class MyTogglzConfiguration implements TogglzConfig {

  public Class<? extends Feature> getFeatureClass() {
    return Features.class;
  }

  public StateRepository getStateRepository() {
    return new FileBasedStateRepository(new File("/tmp/features.properties"));
  }

  public UserProvider getUserProvider() {
    return new ServletUserProvider("admin");
  }

}

Application
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context =
                SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        FeatureManager featureManager = context.getBean(FeatureManager.class);
        StaticFeatureManagerProvider.setFeatureManager(featureManager);
    }
}


Which URI are you using for togglz admin console ?

I'm using http://localhost:8080/togglz-console and even when I specify a path for the console in my application.yml file, it doesn't work.

EDIT
By adding the following in my test project, I managed to get both actuator-based and togglz-console URI working :
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
  <artifactId>togglz-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>4.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
  <artifactId>togglz-console-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>4.4.0</version>
</dependency>

So for your gradle config, I'd suggest you to switch from
    implementation("org.togglz:togglz-spring-boot-starter:3.1.2")
    implementation("org.togglz:togglz-console:3.3.3")

to
    implementation("org.togglz:togglz-spring-boot-starter:4.4.0")
    implementation("org.togglz:togglz-console-spring-boot-starter:4.4.0")

ORIGINAL
From the documentation, you should use the togglz actuator-based-URI

The Actuator Endpoint
By default the togglz-spring-boot starter exposes the togglz endpoint as an actuator one. This allows you to get an overview of all available toggles and also enable and disable features as in the console. By default the endpoint is available via: curl -GET http://localhost:8080/actuator/togglz

So with default configuration, you should try http://localhost:8080/actuator/togglz

Even with that link, I am unfortunately still getting this error: There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). Thanks for your help!

Edited answer to indicate true fix

That worked, thank you so much for your help!

Good to know that my answer helped you solve your problem. Please accept it as correct answer to help other SO users :)

I've got it working in a spring boot app recently and I see you may have missed a configuration property:
togglz.console.enabled: true

That should set up everything given the togglz-spring-boot-starter and console dependencies. I do use version 4.4.0 for both.
